# There is much else to do

Tags: expressions, grammaticality-in-context

I am used to the saying "not much else" but I don't know if the opposite sense is accepted. Is the following correct?

> I know you have much else to do

to indicate that I recognize the person has other things to do than spending time on the subject of the conversation.

Comment: "I know you're busy" is a more idiomatic thing to say in this situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People will understand, "I know you have much else to do." However, I suspect it will sound unusual to many.  It is just a matter of common idioms:

- (negative) not much else
- (positive) a lot more

Yes, it is not symmetrical, but languages are not controlled by logic.

Curiously, "a lot less" is not a replacement for "not much else". In the latter, it is clear few things remain.  The former is extremely vague. For example, I may have completed 12 out of 22 tasks, and a lot less of them remain. But the remaining 10 tasks may take hours to complete, and referring to them as "not much else" would give the wrong impression.

Comment: Though " I understand you have a lot more to do." is probably not what the OP wanted. I would guess at possibly "I understand you have many other things to do."